# Drupal adding extra spacing in text

Tags: drupal, line-breaks

I am on Drupal6, and even with the WYSIWYG disabled, something is putting in white space where I don't expect it.

For example if I enter:

```
<p>HI there (you)</p>
```

All is good.

If I enter:

```
<p>HI there (<strong>you</strong>)</p>
```

I get a space between the opening parentheses and "you":

```
Hi there ( you)
```

When I save and go back in to the body textarea I see:

<p>HI there (
<strong>you</strong>)</p>

So something is putting a line break in the plain text, creating that space. It is not a <br> tag, just a \n in the HTML. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: What input filters do you have enabled?

Comment: Full HTML, HTML Comments, HTML corrector, and URL filter.

Comment: I disabled ckeditor, uninstalled it, and removed the ckeditor directory from the filesystem and confimed there are no lingering ckeditor tables in the db. Still the same problem. So it's not ckeditor...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, this was not ckeditor or filters. I am tidying the output markup using tidy, and forgot I was doing it. The output-xml and ouput-html options, which ASFAIK just control pretty printing, were adding spaces. I set those to false, and the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

Check your input filters and your WYSIWYG Cleanup & Output settings. Here's what works for me:

**Filters**

• HTML Corrector

• URL Filter

**Cleanup & Output Settings**

• Verify HTML

• Preformatted

• Convert `<font>` tags to styles

I'm guessing for some reason it's still applying the cleanup & output settings associated with the wysiwyg even if you have it visually disabled.